# Revit File (.rvt) with materials (textures) import in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 not importing texture properly

Tags: arcgis-pro, texture, revit

Revit File (.rvt) with materials (textures) imported in ArcGis Pro not importing texture properly
in ArcGIS Pro, texture showing texture four times in a 2x2 block, please suggest how to import the Revit file with materials in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 as it is?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a known limitation/defect. Did it work for any Revit files with textures? What is your Revit version?

Comment: @YogeshChavan Revit version is 2021 or 2020, for all said rvt version shows the same as above snapshot split into 4 parts when import in ArcGis Pro 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Modify and use multipach texture and select the texture. It will come properly.